# extract URL from dropbox response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox core api to upload files and then generate shareable links for those files. I want to extract the generated shareable link from the response body but I am unable to do so. The response looks like this:

```
"{\"url\": \"https://www.dropbox.com/pictureicon.png?dl=0\", \"expires\": \"Tue, 01 Jan 2030 00:00:00 +0000\", \"visibility\": \"PUBLIC\"}"
```

To extract the link I have tried the following:

```
console.log('Shared link 2 ' + JSON.stringify(httpResponse.body.url));
```

But the above comes back as undefined. I think its because of the `\` within the response body before and after the url key.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert the response to an object, you need to use `parse`, not `stringify` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)).

```
JSON.parse(httpResponse.body).url
```

Comment: God such a stupid mistake, amazes me how I did not even see this. Thanks for this man!